# Having trouble getting my CSS file to get concatenated in brunch

Tags: css, brunch

I have a css file located here:

```
~/pathTo/viz/viz/app/css/chloropleth.css
```

I am building my brunch application like this:

```
$cd ~/pathTo/viz/viz/
$brunch b
```

When I load ~/pathTo/viz/viz/build/www/index.html I get an error that that the file can't be found at

```
$~/pathTo/viz/viz/build/www/css/app.css
```

It seems like brunch is not finding my css file and concatenating it to that location. My config.coffee file looks like this:

```
  files:
    javascripts:
      joinTo:
        "js/app.js": /^app/
        "js/vendor.js": /^(bower_components|vendor)/
    stylesheets:
      joinTo:
        "css/app.css": /^app/
        "css/vendor.css": /^(bower_components|vendor)/
```

I would think that brunch would pull the css files from ~/pathTo/viz/viz/app/css and add them to `~/pathTo/viz/viz/build/www/css/app.css` but this is not the case.

How do I get brunch to find and concatenate these files?

Answer (score 0):

Brunch's default build directory is `public`. It seems you're expecting the compiled assets to land in a different directory, so you need to specify that in your config:

```
paths:
  public: 'build/www'
```